# What happens when an electrical load is supplied to a motor via a switch and the motor doesn't turn?

Tags: voltage, amperage, load

I'm not from an electrical engineering background. But I'd like to understand what happens when I have the following:
**Electrical 'main power' switch  ------> 'small switch' ------> electrical motor**

In this case, when both switches are ON but the electrical motor is faulty (it doesn't turn, just buzzes) what is happening to the electrical load (if that's the correct term). I expected the electrical motor to start smoking in this scenario but it was the 'small switch' that got fried. The 'small switch' had an Input voltage of AC 90-250V 50/60 Hz and a Max. load: 10 amp. Neither of which would be exceeded by the 'main power' switch.

Comment: What was the voltage and current rating of the power supply? For instance, if the power came from a mains wall outlet, how much current can that outlet provide?

Comment: Probably a large current is flowing into the motor. Large enough to kill your small switch but not large enough to kill your large switch.

Comment: the motor is the electrical load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current through a stalled (not rotating) motor is much higher than the current when it gets up to speed because the rotation of the motor produces a [back-emf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-electromotive_force) that opposes the supply voltage and reduces the current to less than you would expect just from the resistance of the motor windings.

Normally, as you said, it's the motor that gets hot and possibly becomes damaged in this situation, but in your case it seems that the switch gives out first — probably the motor's stall current exceeds its 10 amp rating. Which indicates that this is *not a very safe switch* to use with this motor, or that the switch needs to be protected by a fuse or circuit breaker that will trip at 10 amps or less.

Comment: Or the switch should be used with an appropriately sized relay.